# Dynamic TableLayout with ID's?

Tags: android

I have a working dynamic `TableLayout` that holds user data. Clicking an "Add Event" button brings up a `Dialog` that allows the user to enter data. When the `Dialog` is dismissed, the entered data appears as a new row in the table.

Now, however, I am having trouble allowing the user to EDIT a given row in the table. It seems I need dynamic ID's to give each `TableRow` in order to allow edits. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`setId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) method that will allow you to assign an ID dynamically from your Java code.